# Как удалить строки с определенным значением в столбце?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Необходимо удалить все строки со значениями в определенном столбце содержащем вещественные числа, которые удовлетворяют условию - "Все числа которые больше 300.0".

Я создал переменную, но не знаю, как удалить в DataFrame.

```
to_drop = [i for i in train.Fare if i > 300.0]
```

Как решить данную задачу?

Comment: Что значит "удалить в столбце" - заменить на NaN? Вы можете удалить только строки целиком. Если строки не удалять, то только заменять числа на что-то

Comment: Именно! Строки целиком.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Кажется, что будет легче провести обратную операцию: создать новый датафрейм из старого с теми строками, где числа из столбца Fare будут меньше или равны 300. Пример кода:

```
df = df[df.Fare <= 300]
```

Comment: Вышенаписанное условие понятно, но как его применить, чтобы сохранились и остальные данные. В датафрейме не мало столбцов и строк

Comment: Какие данные вам в итоге нужны? Собираетесь ли вы удалять из датафрейма строки по условию? Если не уелые строки, то просто заменяете нужные вам значения в столбце NaN.

Comment: Вместе со строками.

Comment: Тогда данное решение вам подходит :)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы точно выразили свою мысль и хотите именно *"удалить все **значения** в определенном столбце(вещественные числа), которые удовлетворяют условию"* но оставить все остальные элементы Датафрейма без изменений, то это делается так:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,5,4,3,4,5],
                   'Fare':[100,200,300,400,500,100],
                   'w':[11,15,14,13,14,15]})
df1.loc[df1['Fare']>300,'Fare']='nan'
```

Результат:

```
   x Fare   w
0  1  100  11
1  5  200  15
2  4  300  14
3  3  nan  13
4  4  nan  14
5  5  100  15
```

А если со строками -  то вот так:

```
df1=df1[df1['Fare']<=300]
```

Результат:

```
   x  Fare   w
0  1   100  11
1  5   200  15
2  4   300  14
5  5   100  15
```

Comment: Вместе со строками

Comment: В ответе - оба варианта. Выбирайте. А впредь - выражайте свои желания четко.

Answer (score 2):

Можно воспользоваться методом [DataFrame.query(...)](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

пример данных:

```
threshold = 300
np.random.seed(1234)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(2000, size=(10, 3)), columns=list("abc"))
```

решение:

```
res = df.query("a <= @threshold")
```

результат:

```
      a     b      c
3   279  1257   1178
4    30  1707   1182
9   246   510   1455
```

Comment: Я понимаю, когда `query` используется для сложных запросов, но для простых его использовать как-то странно. Наверное, просто дело привычки )

Comment: @CrazyElf, лично мне .query нравится гораздо больше по-сравнению с .loc[] потому что он легче читается и часто быстрее работает (под капотом используется numexpr). 